# fragment layout can not be referenced?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, navigation-drawer

I am following the tutorial [here](http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/06/android-sliding-navigation-drawer-example.html) to learn how to create an activity with a `NavigationDrawer`.

I followed the tutorial and at the point when it comes to reference my `FragmentLayout` as mentioned below in the code, i found that my `layout` can not be referenced using `R.layout.`.

To solve this I regenerated the `R class` but still the problem remains.

can anyone please tell me why i am getting this error and how to resolve it?

**Note**: the `layout` i wish to reference is named `fragment_layout.xml`
**Code**:

```
public class DetailsFragment extends Fragment {

TextView text;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle  
savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout., container, false);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Please post your imports as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possibilities are likely to be the problem in your code:

Either you have a problem inside one of your XML files (Manifest, layouts, values, etc.)

**OR**

You are not importing the correct **R** file